# Delayed notifications on Samsung Galaxy S21

Tags: samsung, push-notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-21

On many apps on my Samsung Galaxy S21, notifications are significantly delayed. I have tried all suggestions but nothing seems to work.

These suggestions don't solve the problem:
[How do I fix delayed notifications on Android - 1](https://techwiser.com/ways-to-fix-delayed-notifications-on-android/)
[How do I fix delayed notifications on Android - 2](https://www.digitbin.com/fix-delayed-notifications-on-android/)
[How do I fix delayed notifications on Android - 3](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/135909987/delayed-notifications-since-android-12-update?hl=en)

I also tried not to close the apps but only use the Home button. But still, android sooner or later terminates the apps resulting in delayed push notifications.

Comment: You must have tinkered with the settings. Check battery optimisation